# SwiftUI - Stripe STPPaymentContext view not updating with STPPaymentConfiguration

Tags: swift, swiftui, stripe-payments

So I have implemented Stripe into my project. Everything works as intended. However, I do wish to use some of the configuration options available to use. For instance, setting the default payment country to "UK". However, this causes my app to crash as it finds a nil value. I am also trying to use some of the other settings like so:

```
self.config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .full
self.config.appleMerchantIdentifier = "dummy-merchant-id"
self.config.cardScanningEnabled = true
self.config.applePayEnabled = true
```

The only thing within the view that I can seem to change is the `.requiredBillingAddressFields`. Everything else does not seem to register. My code is as followed, I've ripped out what is not related to Stripe for clarity:

```
struct CheckOutView: View {
    @StateObject var paymentContextDelegate: PaymentContextDelegate
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
    @State private var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext!
    
    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            BorderedButton(text: "Pay Now") {
                self.paymentContext.requestPayment()
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        HStack {
            BorderedButton(text: paymentContextDelegate.paymentMethodButtonTitle) {
                self.paymentContext.presentPaymentOptionsViewController()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.paymentContextConfiguration()
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - Configuration
    func paymentContextConfiguration() {


        self.config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .full
        self.config.appleMerchantIdentifier = "dummy-merchant-id"
        self.config.cardScanningEnabled = true
        self.config.applePayEnabled = true
        self.config.verifyPrefilledShippingAddress = true
        self.config.canDeletePaymentOptions = true

        
        
        
        self.paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: self.config, theme: .defaultTheme)
        
        self.paymentContext.delegate = self.paymentContextDelegate
        
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
            .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
            .compactMap({$0})
            .first?.windows
            .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).last
        
        
        self.paymentContext.hostViewController = keyWindow?.rootViewController
        
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a guess, but perhaps the config options are applying, but it's just that the other requirements for the features they enable are not met? How exactly do you determine that everything else except billing address does not register?

For example `applePayEnabled` will only result in the Apple Pay option appearing if the device itself supports Apple Pay(on a physical device with a real card in your wallet it would work(but you must have a real Apple Merchant ID), on simulators it can be patchy).

For `cardScanningEnabled` maybe you don't have the entitlement enabled in your app? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios#card-scanning-beta

A simple way to check if the config applies is maybe to set `requiredShippingAddressFields` since it's self-contained and very visual.

Comment: I had a feeling Apple pay needed Capabilities, which is fine, but even trying to set the default country to UK (using an ISO code as Stripe API states) causes my application to crash as it's found a nil value, which does not make sense and confuses me. And yes,I can tamper with `requiredShippingAddressFields`. I chose to opt out of this option, however, I can tamper with it for sure. Edit - You was right about the card scanning. I did not have the entitlements.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the ISO code is `GB` and you are trying `UK`? Note sure why that would cause a crash about a nil value, hard to say without seeing the exact code you try + stack trace of the error.

Comment: I've tried GB/UK. I have even tried changing `paymentContext.paymentCountry` and this causes the same issue, which is weird.